# Creating a Majority Graph from multiple preference orders

Tags: decision-theory, voting-theory

I can't find much on voting theory on this exceptional site.

I am trying to find a way of constructing a majority graph based on a few preference. When I try to construct one, I end up breaking the asymmetry condition.

The preferences are like the following.
There are 5 candidates overall and 3 voters.

**Voter 1 c3>c2>c4>c1>c5**

**Voter 2 c4>c2>c5>c3>c1**

**Voter 3 c3>c5>c2>c1>c4**

Any ideas or references to materials are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: (Showing my efforts in constructing a Majority Graph that represents the above preference orders.) (Attached) [Majority graph attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMIQT.png))

This attempt breaks asymmetry and also it is not complete.
More specifically asymmetry is broken between **c2** and **c4** (based on the first 2 preference orders) and between **c5** and **c3** (based on the 2nd and 3rd preference orders.) 
 I am not able to find an example similar to this, which was quite surprising.

Comment: Welcome to this exceptional site :-). Please show your attempts at constructing the graph and how you broke the asymmetry condition (why the quotes?).

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the warm welcome, I've spent many hours on this site. This is my first question though. I updated the post with some of my work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could you provide your definition of a majority graph? I would have thought that it's a graph that contains a directed edge from $C$ to $D$ exactly if a majority of voters prefer $C$ to $D$. By this definition, the graph would automatically be asymmetric. You seem to be referring to a graph that contains a directed edge for each separate voter preference of $C$ over $D$. There's no reason why such a graph should be asymmetric, and I don't see why one would call it a "majority graph".

Comment: Silly me. I knew I was missing something very fundamental  about building majority graphs. You are absolutely right, i missed the 'majority' part of the definition, which is why all the examples I have seen have an even number of voters. I tried constructing a graph for each one and tried to merge them.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered: A majority graph contains a directed edge from $C$ to $D$ exactly if a majority of voters prefer $C$ to $D$. Such a graph is asymmetric by construction, since it cannot be that a majority of voters prefer $C$ to $D$ and a majority of voters also prefer $D$ to $C$.